# How to export note information from SCAMP to synth without rtmidi?

Tags: python, midi

I'm using Python with SCAMP and looking to export the resulting musical data to a synth with a USB MIDI interface. Online tutorials tell me I need the rtmidi package, but trying to install it generates an unknown error message. Is there a way around this?

The error message I get upon trying to install rtmidi is very non-descript.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.